# Update with Sub Query Derived Table Error

Tags: sql, sybase, derived-table

I have the following SQL statement to simply update the `#temp` temp table with the latest package version number in our Sybase 15 database.

```
UPDATE t
SET versionId = l.latestVersion
FROM #temp t INNER JOIN (SELECT gp.packageId
                                , MAX(gp.versionId) latestVersion
                         FROM Group_Packages gp 
                         WHERE gp.groupId IN (SELECT groupId 
                                              FROM User_Group 
                                              WHERE userXpId = 'someUser')
                         GROUP BY gp.packageId) l
ON t.packageId = l.packageId
```

To me (mainly Oracle & SQL Server experience more than Sybase) there is little wrong with this statement. However, Sybase throws an exception:

```
You cannot use a derived table in the FROM clause of an UPDATE or DELETE statement.
```

Now, I don't get what the problem is here. I assume it is because of the aggregation / GROUP BY being used. Of course, I could put the sub query in a temp table and join on it but I really want to know what the 'correct' method should be and what the hell is wrong.

Any ideas or guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is a limitation of Sybase (not allowing derived tables) in the `FROM` clause of the `UPDATE`. Perhaps you can rewrite like this:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.versionId = l.versionId
FROM #temp t
  INNER JOIN 
    Group_Packages l
      ON t.packageId = l.packageId
WHERE
    l.groupId IN ( SELECT groupId 
                   FROM User_Group 
                   WHERE userXpId = 'someUser')
  AND
    l.versionId =
        ( SELECT MAX(gp.versionId)
          FROM Group_Packages gp 
          WHERE gp.groupId IN ( SELECT groupId 
                                FROM User_Group 
                                WHERE userXpId = 'someUser')
            AND gp.packageId = l.packageId
        ) ;
```

Comment: That seems to be the one. Thank you. Just had to make a small tweak: `UPDATE t` to `UPDATE #temp`. Frustrating that something so simple has to be written in such a way!

Comment: I think that @valexhome has come up with a shorter version.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that SYBASE doesn't support nested queries in UPDATE FROM class. [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436084/how-do-i-update-multiple-columns-with-a-subquery-in-a-single-statement)

Try to use this:

```
UPDATE #temp
SET versionId =  (SELECT MAX(gp.versionId) latestVersion
                         FROM Group_Packages gp 
                         WHERE gp.packageId=#temp.packageId
                                and
                               gp.groupId IN (SELECT groupId 
                                              FROM User_Group 
                                              WHERE userXpId = 'someUser')

                         )
```

And also what if l.latestVersion is NULL? Do you want update #temp with null ? if not then add WHERE:

```
    WHERE (SELECT MAX(gp.versionId)
                          ....
                                 ) is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table alias for #temp is called "t" and your original table is called "t".

My guess is that this is the problem.

I think you want to start with:

```
update #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this syntax work in Sybase?

```
update dstTable T
set (T.field1, T.field2, T.field3) = 
       (select S.value1, S.value2, S.value3
        from srcTable S
         where S.key = T.Key);
```

I believe the correlated subquery can be as complicated as you like (including using CTE. etc).  It just has to project the right number (and type) of values.

Comment: I've been told this is Oracle specific syntax.  :-(